# Namespace in Android

Tags: android, namespaces

`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

```
`xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`
```

What is the difference between these three namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

These just defines the properties.

`xmlns:android` - defines the properties/attributes provided by the android framework, like `width`, `height` etc.. these are the default properties provided by android framework, which you use in the xml.

`xmlns:app` - these are the additional/extra properties which you define while creating a custom-view.
For example, if you are creating a your `CustomView` for inflating a `Circle`, apart from giving the properties like `android:width` or `android:height`, you can give your custom properties like `radius` or `color` and use the same in the xml using app:radius or `app:color`.

`xmlns:tools` - these are tools properties/attributes provided by the android framework that enables design-time features and only available during design time.

When you build your app, the build tools remove these attributes so there is no effect on your APK size or runtime behavior.

You use some of these properties like `tools:visibility="invisible"` etc.. which is only effects during design time, but not when the app is build and apk is pushed on device. It's basically used for the ease of design.

Tools attribute reference
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes